# Sum only if particular value is present in a node and exclude others

Tags: sum, xslt-2.0

I'm using XSLT 2.0 to sum only particular values as per below conditions:

- If wd:Analytical_amount is greater than 0, use analytical amount values
- If wd:Analytical_amount is equal to 0, use total invoice values

Below is sample XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Body>
       <wd:Report_Data
           xmlns:wd="trans_file">
           <wd:Report_Entry>
               <wd:Transaction_Number>415077</wd:Transaction_Number>
               <wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
                   <wd:Analytical_amount>500</wd:Analytical_amount>
               </wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
               <wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
                   <wd:Analytical_amount>0</wd:Analytical_amount>
               </wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
               <wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
                   <wd:Analytical_amount>1000</wd:Analytical_amount>
               </wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
               <wd:Total_Invoice_amount>5000</wd:Total_Invoice_amount>
           </wd:Report_Entry>
           <wd:Report_Entry>
               <wd:Transaction_Number>494700</wd:Transaction_Number>
               <wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
                   <wd:Analytical_amount>0</wd:Analytical_amount>
               </wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
               <wd:Total_Invoice_amount>2000</wd:Total_Invoice_amount>
           </wd:Report_Entry>
<!--Edit: added more XML nodes -->
               <wd:Report_Entry>
              <wd:Transaction_Number>494111</wd:Transaction_Number>
              <wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
                  <wd:Analytical_amount>0</wd:Analytical_amount>
              </wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
              <wd:Total_Invoice_amount>1000</wd:Total_Invoice_amount>
          </wd:Report_Entry>
           <wd:Report_Entry>
              <wd:Transaction_Number>494222</wd:Transaction_Number>
              <wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
                  <wd:Analytical_amount>500</wd:Analytical_amount>
              </wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group>
              <wd:Total_Invoice_amount>4000</wd:Total_Invoice_amount>
          </wd:Report_Entry>
       </wd:Report_Data>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

XSLT used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:wd="trans_file"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xd;&#xa;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'|'"/>        
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">

          <xsl:value-of select="count(wd:Report_Entry/wd:Transaction_Number)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(//wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group/wd:Analytical_amount[. != '0']),'#.00')"/> 
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>    
        <xsl:if test="wd:Report_Entry/wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group/*[not(wd:Analytical_amount != 0)]">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(wd:Report_Entry/wd:Total_Invoice_amount),'#.##')"/>
                      
                      <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result I'm getting:
2|1500.00|7000.0|

Expected text based output:
2|1500.00|2000.0|

New result after editing XML:
4|2000.00|6000.0|

Answer (score 0):

An XSLT-1.0 solution would be

```
<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(wd:Report_Entry/wd:Transaction_Number)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="sum(wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group/wd:Analytical_amount) > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group/wd:Analytical_amount),'#.00')"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(wd:Total_Invoice_amount,'#.00')"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
</xsl:template>
```

And an XSLT-2.0 solution even simpler

```
<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(wd:Report_Entry/wd:Transaction_Number)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
    <xsl:value-of select="if (sum(wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group/wd:Analytical_amount) > 0) then format-number(sum(wd:Customer_Invoice_Lines_group/wd:Analytical_amount),'#.00') else format-number(wd:Total_Invoice_amount,'#.00')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you @zx485. What about if I have more XML nodes and sum the Analytical amount and Invoice amount is needed in 2 fields only? Edited the XML in question

New result after editing XML:
4|2000.00|6000.0|

Comment: Changing the question after an answer is frowned on SO. I'm sorry, but I really don't know what the expected input and output should be at that state.